# Deeplinking in android application

Tags: android, deep-linking, intentfilter, chrome-custom-tabs

I'm trying to introduce a deeplinking in my application. This is the process:

- Open the Android app
- Click a button
- Button opens a chrome custom tab with specific url
- Chrome browser shows a form
- When you submit the form, you redirect to payment page (payment page url is something like that xyz.com/objetId?callbackUrl=encodedCharacters) When I am redirected to this payment url, I want to go back to a different activity for the same Android app. Because for this url there is a webView intent. I want to show it in the app.

I tried to add intent-filters for deeplinking. When I submit to form still, I'm staying in the chrome custom tab. (I mean in the browser) But I want to go back to app.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem with custom scheme in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<data android:host="backToApplication"
android:scheme="someSchemeLikeHttp"/>
```

I was using https as scheme but for links, default application is default browser in the phone. I changed the schema and I'm sending my schema and host in the url callback like

```
?callback_url=someSchemeLikeHttp://backToApplication
```

Now it's working for me.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you need to listen for submit action in webview by using java script interfaces. Webview has `addJavascriptInterface` method to do that. Android documentation here [Binding JavaScript code to Android code](https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html) and the examples
[example_1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19714322/how-do-i-detect-a-webpage-form-submission-in-android-app)
[example_2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20917793/1512199)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I want to got to Android app, after chrome tabs. When I open a specific link in chrome tabs, I want to open my app with this specific link (webview). How can I listen submit action in webview in that case?

Comment: I added my solution. But thanks anyway, I didn't know this part. Good to know.

Comment: Hi, I think i misunderstood your problem. I thought you open browser inside of your application. Yeah you basically wanted to open your app from url   [link](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking.html)